# Reverse engineer maximization problem:

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, economics

I am looking for a function $u(x) : R^+ \to R$, such that

$\frac{w}{1+p}$ is a solution to $\max_x u(x) \text{ s.t. } px \leq w$.

Is there some **continuous** function for which this is the case? I need it for a possible counterexample, or to find out more about what properties of $u(x)$ might be useful for a proof I am working on.

If you want (economic) background: I am looking for the utility function that induces said demand function. I want to show that $\pi(p)=p \cdot x^*(p,w)$ has or doesn't have a maximum if $x^*(p,w)$ is the solution to the above maximization problem, where $u(x) : R^+ \to R$ is a continuos, strictly quasi-concave function. Of course, $ \frac{wp}{1+p}$ has no maximum, that's why I am interested in the generating utility function.

Comment: Can $u$ explicitly depend on $w$ and $p$? If not, then it seems difficult, if not impossible, to specify a $u$ that gives you the solution you want.